# Passing data between fragments with an Observable when X happens

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I'm fairly new to RxJava, and I was thinking if my problem could be solved with it.

I have an activity with two fragments: a header fragment hosted inside a CollapsingToolbarLayout, and a body fragment. The header fragment has a recycler view with posts, and the body fragment shows comments related to the current post shown in the header fragment.

Now, the comments are loaded immediately when the recycler view binds a post. However, I'd like to only load the comments when the user starts collapsing the toolbar. I have a listener set up for the toolbar which gets invoked when the user starts dragging the toolbar up, but I don't really know how to hook it up to the body fragment using the current post in the header fragment.

To describe it in pseudo-code, it's something like this:

```
// Activity has this method invoked when toolbar starts collapsing;
// It's invoked only once per "drag"        
public void onToolbarCollapsing() {
    // Somehow should pass the Post to the body fragment..?
}

// The header fragment has this method invoked when a post is bound
public void onPostBound(Post post) {
    // Create an Observable<Post> and pass it to activity..?
}

// The body fragment could probably observe the observable?
```

At the moment, I have the `Activity` implement an `ActivityCallback`:

```
public interface ActivityCallback {
    void loadCommentsFor(Post post);
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCallback {

    @Override void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create fragments, set activity callback to the header fragment
        HeaderFragment header = new HeaderFragment();
        header.setActivityCallback(this);

        BodyFragment body = new BodyFragment();

        // Set fragments to the view etc.
    }

    // Implementation
    @Override
    public void loadCommentsFor(Post post) {
        // Just pass the post object to the body fragment
        bodyFragment.loadCommentsFor(post);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that if in this particular situation you gain something by using RxJava.

But you could use something like [PublishSubject](http://[http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/PublishSubject.html][1]%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/PublishSubject.html) to do this communication.

header ----> Posts (subject) ----> body

In other words, header emits/sends/publish posts, and the body fragment listens/observes/reacts to it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCallback {

    @Override void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PublishSubject<Post> posts = PublishSubject.create()

        HeaderFragment header = new HeaderFragment(posts);
        BodyFragment body = new BodyFragment(posts);

       // Set fragments to the view etc.
   }

}
```

The HeaderFragment should emit the posts:

```
private final PublishSubject<Post> posts;

public HeaderFragment(PublishSubject<Post> posts) {
    this.posts = posts;
}

public void onToolbarCollapsing() {
    this.posts.onNext(theCurrentPost);
}
```

If the method onToolbarCollapsing is in the Activity and not in the HeaderFragment, there is no problem, since anyone can publish to the post's subject and the body fragment will react accordingly.

And the body fragment will listen to it:

```
private final PublishSubject<Post> posts;

public BodyFragment(PublishSubject<Post> posts) {
    this.posts = posts;
}

//Do something with the post
//this.posts.subscribe(new Observer<Posts>())
//Such as fetchComments
this.posts.flatMap(new Function<Post, SingleSource<List<Comment>>() {
    @Override
    public SingleSource<List<Comment>>apply(Post post) throws Exception {
        //Should return a Single<List<Comment>>
        return fetchComments(post);
    }
})
.subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<Comment>>() {
   void onSuccess(List<Comment> comments) {
      //update the adapter
   }
});
```

OBS:

I passed the subject to the constructors for simplicity.
You could use onAttach() or onCreateView() to @Inject them (Dagger2, Guice, etc)